# Kdenlive color picker / dropper selects interface instead of video

Tags: gnome, colors, interface, video-editor, kdenlive

This problem appears to be specific to Kdenlive so far. On Xubuntu 16.04, using the color picker of e.g. the "White Balance" effect to color correct a video automatically would select a pixel from the video preview itself.

Now, on Ubuntu 18.04, it seems that the color picker sometimes selects a pixel from the video, sometimes the interface window's color and other times seemingly random a green color that isn't in the video frame.

The GIMP color picker works on both the interface and the loaded image, which is fine. The Kdenlive color picker visually looks different, but does not reliably select the actual video. The problem happens in both versions 17.12 from the Ubuntu repository and 18.12 from the official PPA, leading me to believe this could be a GNOME-related issue.

Is there anything that can be done about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my Droplet picker problem! Ubuntu 18.04.1/AMD FX with Radeon video. The color picker was only showing grey or black  in Kdenlive chroma key.

I updated to an appimage, `./kdenlive-18.12.1b-x86_64.appimage`, and the droplet color picker was still not functioning.

Solved it by:

- Select color key box (blue default), which opens Select color dialogue.
- Then select Pick screen color tab.
- Finally select your chroma color.

And Eureka! A nice clean key.